# NUnit and testing in different threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, nunit, semaphore

I'm testing an application. A `[TearDown]` methods contains another method which sends a request a server. This one is pretty slow. Meanwhile a server is unable to handle more than 3 requests at the same time.

So I decided to use a semaphore.

```
   [TestFixture]
    public class TestBase
    {
        private const int MaxThreadsCount = 3;
        private readonly Semaphore _semaphore = new Semaphore(MaxThreadsCount, MaxThreadsCount);

        [SetUp]
        public virtual void Setup()
        {
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void CleanUp()
        {
            //...some code
            new Thread(_ => SendRequestAsync("url/of/a/server", parameters)).Start();
        }

        private void SendRequestAsync(string url, NameValueCollection parameters)
        {
            _semaphore.WaitOne();
            string result = MyServerHelper.SendRequest(url, parameters); 
            Assert.That(string.IsNullOrEmpty(result), Is.False, "SendRequest returned false");
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test01()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test02()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test03()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }
        //...........................
        [Test]
        public void TestN()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
        }
    }
```

However it seems like it does not work properly. Now in log file on a server there are no records, which means a server does not receive any requests.

1) What did I do wrong?

2) How do I initialize a semaphore:

```
private readonly Semaphore _semaphore = new Semaphore(MaxThreadsCount, MaxThreadsCount);
```

or

```
private readonly Semaphore _semaphore = new Semaphore(0, MaxThreadsCount);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) What did I do wrong?

The test runner is probably ending the test process before the thread has finished (or even started). You can verify it using something like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) to verify there is no communication between the test and the server.

Is there a reason why you need to run it in a separate thread? Unless you are specifically testing threaded code, avoid it because it just creates complexities. Call it as you would normally. It also means any exception or error thrown will be caught by the test runner and reported in the test results.

If a test is taking too long (and you cannot fix the root cause like the server speed) consider an IoC container like AutoFac or reference counting to share this between tests that need it. Also consider running the tests [in parallel](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=pnunit&r=2.5), too.

> 2) How do I initialize a semaphore:

The first argument to the [Semaphore class constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1hct27h.aspx) is the initial number of requests. In this case, you probably want to initialize it to 0 since you have no requests running initially.

Note that a semaphore may help the test not send more than three requests but it will not help the server if tests are running concurrently but you probably realise that.

Comment: <<Is there a reason why you need to run it in a separate thread? >> Because `MyServerHelper.SendRequest` are slow and blocks all others tests untill it get finished.

Comment: @AlexMaslakov Maybe manage this using an IoC container like AutoFac or reference counting so you share this between tests that need it. Maybe consider running the tests in parallel, too (see http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=pnunit&r=2.5).

Comment: <<The test runner is probably ending the test process before the thread has finished (or even started).>> Is there any way to make test runner wait until the last thread is finished?

Comment: @AlexMaslakov It depends on the test runner. The default NUnit does do not wait, if I recall correctly, and I do not know a way of telling them to wait (other than moving the code into the main thread as recommended by the answers above).

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that unit tests should be testing small units of functionality.  You shouldn't need to create multiple threads to get your tests working.  If you have slow external dependencies (like a network connection or database); you can define interfaces to abstract that away.

You should be able to test the behaviour you want without the threads.  We can just assume that threads work - we're worried about the code you have.  Presumably, somewhere in your code you have a counter that indicates the number of active connections or requests; or some other way of determining if you can accept another connection.

You want to test what happens when a request comes in, when you are already at the max.

So write a test that does that.  Set that counter to the max, call the open connection code, and verify that it fails with the error you expect.

Answer (score 0):

There are scenarios in which you want to use a test framework to run integration tests with lengthy operations and processes starting multiple threads.

Then OFC you test will run until it starts a new thread or await a long task and suddenly the test ends before the whole process has executed.

The issue with `Thread.Sleep` is that it is very much akin to Cargo Cult programing. You will decide to let the test run for at least a certain amount of time which may vary based on the machine running the tests and your continuous build systems is not going to be very fast if everyone uses that strategy.

Here is a better solution:

```
[Test]
public async Task TestWithTimeOut()
{
    //You can set a very long timeout here
    var timeOut = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    var testExecutionTask = new Task(
        () =>
        {               
            //Test execution and assertion goes here        
            //it should not contain await - use .GetAwaiter().GetResult() instead if needed
        });
        
    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeOut).ContinueWith(_=> throw new TimeoutException());
    
    Func<Task> f = () => Task.WhenAny(testExecutionTask, timeoutTask);
    
    await f.Should().NotThrowAsync();
};
```